# Gerrit 2.12 "Cannot Merge" chain of commits ending in merge

Tags: git, gerrit

We have two distinct repositories on our gerrit server: shared, and main. Periodically, shared/master is merged into main/master, in the form of a long chain of commits to main with a Merge Commit at the top.

This time around, there were some conflicts in the merge that needed to be addressed; one file had internal conflicts, and another had been modified in shared but deleted in main. I used git add and git rm respectively to fix the conflicts and then git commit to finish the merge.

I sent it up to gerrit to review and complete the merge, but it will not let me merge them in. The commit which introduced those conflicts has "Cannot Merge" in bold red letters on it, as does everything dependent on it. Even though the Merge Commit fixes those conflicts in the end, it will not let me click "Submit including parents."

I recently upgraded our gerrit server to 2.12, and this is the first time since then I have had to do this on this version, but I did it routinely on previous versions. Is there something I should be doing differently now?

(Note: seems that this may be a [recent](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/repo-discuss/g1cpsRgs2bo) [bug](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=3811).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been accepted as a [confirmed bug](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=3811). I worked around it by pushing directly to refs/heads/master.